# Is there any documention as to what versions of external libs (libfreetype, etc) were used to produce a PyPi build of Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

For compliance uses, I'm looking to see if there is any documentation anywhere that lists what versions of the external libs were used to build a given version of Pillow.

Eg: if I "pip install Pillow==6.0.0", what versions of the external libs am I getting?

Comment: Do you mean `pip list pillow`?

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell; but unfortunately not. I'm looking for the actual compiled libs that go into Pillow itself.  I mentioned `libfreetype` because I know that is one that's in it, but I don't know what version.  If I go into the dir that pip installs it into (Ubuntu 18.04, in my case), I see a reference to libfreetype.so.6.16.1 in the `RECORD` file, but there is such freetype version on the freetype site that I can find.  So I'm wondering what version of the libs that went INTO the Pillow distribution.